# How to find the first occurrence of a negative value for each factor

Tags: r, group-by

I am working with weather data and trying to find the first time a temperature is negative for each winter season. I have a data frame with a column for the winter season (1,2,3,etc.), the temperature, and the ID.

I can get the first time the temperature is negative with this code:

```
 FirstNegative <- min(which(df$temp<=0))
```

but it only returns the first value, and not one for each season.

I know I somehow need to group_by season, but how do I incorporate this?

For example,

```
season<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5)
temp<-c(2,-1,0,-1,3,-1,0,-1,2,-1,4,5,-1,-1,2)
ID<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)

df <- cbind(season,temp,ID)
```

Ideally I want a table that looks like this from the above dummy code:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSOjM.png)

```
season id_firstnegative
[1,]      1                2
[2,]      2                4
[3,]      3                8
[4,]      4               10
[5,]      5               13
```

Comment: @arg0naut91 - `which.min` will not give the correct result if there are values lower than the first time a negative temperature was noted.

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail, I've overlooked that - then it's not a complete dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `base R` option using `subset` and `aggregate`

```
aggregate(ID ~ season, subset(df, temp < 0), head, 1)
#   season ID
#1      1  2
#2      2  4
#3      3  8
#4      4 10
#5      5 13
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said, I believe you could solve this by simply grouping season and examining the *first index of IDs below zero within that grouping*. However, the ordering of your data will be important, so ensure that each season has the correct ordering before using this possible solution.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

season<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5)

temp<-c(2,-1,0,-1,3,-1,0,-1,2,-1,4,5,-1,-1,2)

ID<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)

df<- tibble(season,temp,ID)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(season) %>%
  mutate(firstNeg = ID[which(temp<0)][1]) %>%
  distinct(season, firstNeg) # Combine only unique values of these columns for reduced output
```

This will provide output like:

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   season [5]
  season firstNeg
   <dbl>    <dbl>
1      1        2
2      2        4
3      3        8
4      4       10
5      5       13
```

Comment: Try `summarise` instead of `mutate`, would make the `distinct` part obsolete

Comment: Very true; I kept `mutate` in the process so it was easy to look back and see how `firstNeg` looked prior to collapsing. But yes, it is unnecessary if one only wants the final summarized table.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

season<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5)

temp<-c(2,-1,0,-1,3,-1,0,-1,2,-1,4,5,-1,-1,2)

ID<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)

df<-as.data.frame(cbind(season,temp,ID))

df %>%
    dplyr::filter(temp < 0) %>%
    group_by(season) %>%
    dplyr::filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Comment: This suggests a really neat *data.table* translation of `df[temp < 0, .(firstneg = .I[1]), by=season]`